# how to reverse the order of the output

Tags: python, reverse, iterable

What are the possible ways of reversing order of any output?

For example, if I have a code like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

This is fairly a simple example of course. I can just say

```
for i in range(9, -1, -1):
    print(i)
```

But what happens when you have very complicated functions, lists, maps, arrays, etc. So my question is: Is there a generic way (or ways) to reverse the order of any output?

I've been thinking about pushing every element (element can be anything) onto a stack, then pop() elements and printing the popped element. But maybe there are better solutions

Comment: You can use reverse() on your list first and then iterate over it.

Comment: for `lists` and `arrays` you can use `list[::-1]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) builtin:

```
for i in reversed(range(10)):
    print(i)
```

output:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way? I thought stacks would be more efficient

Comment: @goku can you provide a real-life example of what you try to achieve?

Comment: I was solving a graph problem and was trying to find the path between two vertices. And the most intuitive way doing this, ended up printing out the result in reverse order. I thought rather than changing the code I can reverse the output. Then I generalized the problem (I did not pose the actual problem because I guess it is irrelevant). So I am asking for general ways because more than once I’ve come acrossed the situation where I wanted to reverse the order of output without changing anything.

Comment: @goku it might be worth posting your specific case as a separate question. If you can reverse the output directly in your algorithm this will likely be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(10)[::-1]:
    print(i)
```

OUTPUT

```py
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```